# How to manage reactivity flow in this Shiny example?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The code at the bottom almost works perfectly except for one pesky bug I can't figure out. In some way I have botched the flow of reactives. The image below shows how this App works. Basically, the user can input into the top matrix (`base_input`) generated by function `matInputBase()` and can then input into more detailed time scenarios in the next 2 input matrixes (`var_1_input` and `var_2_input`) generated by function `matInputFlex()`. Importantly, this code allows the user to save and upload matrix input scenarios. The issue I am having is if the user has set the `sliderInput()` for the time window (`input$periods`) to some value in the current session, and then tries uploading a saved scenario that has a different value for `input$periods`, it takes 2 upload attempts: in the first upload attempt, the current session `input$periods` is correctly reset to the uploaded `input$periods`, but not the values for `var_1_input` and `var_2_input` matrixes; but in the 2nd upload attempt, the values for `var_1_input` and `var_2_input` matrixes are then correctly uploaded. It takes 2 upload attempts, I would like the upload to work correctly in one upload attempt, in those circumstances where current session `input$periods` <> upload `input$periods`. How can this be fixed?

Caveats. This has been a game a whack-a-mole. I have resolved the above issue using observers, but then another issue arises where it takes 2 moves of the `sliderInput()` to reset those 2 input matrixes (should take only one move of `sliderInput()` to reset the matrixes, as it does in this version of code, which is correct).

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(0.20),2,1,dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matStretch <- function(col_name,time_window,mat) {
  mat[, 1] <- pmin(mat[, 1], time_window)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = time_window, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, col_name)))
  df[, col_name] <- ifelse(
    seq_along(df[, 1]) %in% mat[, 1], mat[match(seq_along(df[, 1]), mat[, 1]), 2], 
    0    )
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton('modal_upload', 'Upload'),
    downloadButton("save_btn", "Save"),
    sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
    h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
    matInputBase("base_input"),
    actionButton("resetVectorBtn", "Reset"),
    uiOutput("Vectors")
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("table2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$periods, {
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      updateMatrixInput(
        session,
        paste0("var_", i, "_input"),
        value = matrix(c(input$periods, input$base_input[i, 1]),1,2,dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
      )
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
   
  updateVariableInput <- function(i, current_input, session) {
    matrix_name <- paste0("var_", i, "_input")
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, matrix_name,
      value = matrix(c(input$periods, current_input),1,2,dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
  }
  
  prev_base_input <- reactiveValues(data = matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 1))
  
  observeEvent(input$base_input, {
    for (i in 1:2) {
      if (is.na(prev_base_input$data[i,1]) || input$base_input[i,1] != prev_base_input$data[i,1]){
        updateMatrixInput(
          session, 
          paste0("var_", i, "_input"), 
          value = matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[i,1]),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
        )
        prev_base_input$data[i, 1] <- input$base_input[i, 1]
      }
    }
  })
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    varNames <- c("Var_1","Var_2")
    tagList(
      lapply(1:2, function(i) {
        list(
          h5(strong(paste("Adjust", varNames[i], "(Y) at time X:"))),
          matInputFlex(paste0("var_", i, "_input"), input$periods, isolate(input$base_input[i, 1]))
        )
      })
    )
  })
  
  output$save_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0("scenario", ".rds"),
    content = function(file) saveRDS(
      list(periods = input$periods,
           var_1_input = input$var_1_input,
            var_2_input = input$var_2_input
      ), file)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_upload, {
    showModal(modalDialog(fileInput("upload_file_input", "Upload:", accept = c('.rds'))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$upload_file_input, {
    uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)
    updateSliderInput(session, "periods", value = uploaded_values$periods)
    updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", value = uploaded_values$var_1_input)
    updateMatrixInput(session, "var_2_input", value = uploaded_values$var_2_input)

    output$Vectors <- renderUI({
      input$resetVectorBtn
      tagList(
        h5(strong("Adjust Var_1 (Y) at time X:")),
        matInputFlex("var_1_input", uploaded_values$periods, isolate(input$base_input[1, 1])),
        h5(strong("Adjust Var_2 (Y) at time X:")),
        matInputFlex("var_2_input", uploaded_values$periods, isolate(input$base_input[2, 1]))
      )
    })
    output$table2 <- renderTable(
      cbind(matStretch("Var_1", uploaded_values$periods, uploaded_values$var_1_input),
            matStretch("Var_2", uploaded_values$periods, uploaded_values$var_2_input)
            )
    )
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$var_1_input, {
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
      cbind(matStretch("Var_1", input$periods, input$var_1_input),
            matStretch("Var_2", input$periods, input$var_2_input)
            )
    })
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(0.20),2,1,dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matStretch <- function(col_name,time_window,mat) {
  mat[, 1] <- pmin(mat[, 1], time_window)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = time_window, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, col_name)))
  df[, col_name] <- ifelse(
    seq_along(df[, 1]) %in% mat[, 1], mat[match(seq_along(df[, 1]), mat[, 1]), 2], 
    0    )
  return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton('modal_upload', 'Upload'),
    downloadButton("save_btn", "Save"),
    sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 10, value = 10),
    h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
    matInputBase("base_input"),
    actionButton("resetVectorBtn", "Reset"),
    uiOutput("matricesInputs")
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("table2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  prev_base_input <- reactiveValues(data = matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 1))
  
  observeEvent(input$base_input, {
    for (i in 1:2) {
      if (is.na(prev_base_input$data[i,1]) || input$base_input[i,1] != prev_base_input$data[i,1]){
        updateMatrixInput(
          session, 
          paste0("var_", i, "_input"), 
          value = matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[i,1]),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
        )
        prev_base_input$data[i, 1] <- input$base_input[i, 1]
      }
    }
  })
  
  Var1 <- reactiveVal(matrix(c(10, 0), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))))
  Var2 <- reactiveVal(matrix(c(10, 20), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))))

  output$matricesInputs <- renderUI({
    varNames <- c("Var_1","Var_2")
    tagList(
      h5(strong(paste("Adjust", varNames[1], "(Y) at time X:"))),
      matInputFlex(
        "var_1_input", input$periods, Var1()[2]
      ),
      h5(strong(paste("Adjust", varNames[2], "(Y) at time X:"))),
      matInputFlex(
        "var_2_input", input$periods, Var2()[2]
      )
    )
  }) |> bindEvent(input$periods)
  
  observeEvent(input$resetVectorBtn, {
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, 
      "var_1_input", 
      value = matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, 
      "var_2_input", 
      value = matrix(c(input$periods,input$base_input[2,1]),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y")))
    )
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable(
    cbind(matStretch("Var_1", input$periods, input$var_1_input),
          matStretch("Var_2", input$periods, input$var_2_input)
    )
  )
  
  output$save_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0("scenario", ".rds"),
    content = function(file) saveRDS(
      list(periods = input$periods,
           var_1_input = input$var_1_input,
           var_2_input = input$var_2_input
      ), file)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_upload, {
    showModal(modalDialog(fileInput("upload_file_input", "Upload:", accept = c('.rds'))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$upload_file_input, {
    uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)
    updateSliderInput(session, "periods", value = uploaded_values$periods)
    Var1(uploaded_values$var_1_input)
    Var2(uploaded_values$var_2_input)
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  observe({
    v1 <- matrix(c(input$periods, Var1()[2]), 1, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("X","Y")))
    v2 <- matrix(c(input$periods, Var2()[2]), 1, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("X","Y")))
    updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", value = v1)
    updateMatrixInput(session, "var_2_input", value = v2)
    Var1(matrix(c(input$periods, input$base_input[1, 1]),1,2,dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))))
    Var2(matrix(c(input$periods, input$base_input[2, 1]),1,2,dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))))
  }) |> bindEvent(input$periods, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that appears to work, though I hope to get solutions from others because my confidence in working with reactivity is shaken. Replace the below `observeEvent()` with the `observeEvent(input$upload_file_input, {...})` in OP code and it should now work. Explanation:

1. Upon uploading, input$periods is immediately updated to match the uploaded scenario.
   An observe block is then used to check if input$periods matches the uploaded value.
2. If it does, the matrix inputs (var_1_input and var_2_input) are updated accordingly.

Code:

```
observeEvent(input$upload_file_input, {
    req(input$upload_file_input)
    uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)

# Update input$periods with the uploaded value
updateSliderInput(session, "periods", value = uploaded_values$periods)

observe({
  # Proceed only if input$periods matches the uploaded value
  if (input$periods == uploaded_values$periods) {
    updateMatrixInput(session, "var_1_input", value = uploaded_values$var_1_input)
    updateMatrixInput(session, "var_2_input", value = uploaded_values$var_2_input)
  }
})
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
```